# Exception in thread main, out of bounds and parsing Date class

Tags: java, parsing, date, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a problem that I can't resolve by my self;
this is a part of the code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class prog1 
{
// Effettua il parsing di una stringa della forma giorno/mese/anno e     restituisce l'oggetto Date corrispondente.
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static Date parseDate( String s ) 
{
    String[] f = s.split("/");
    return new Date(Integer.parseInt(f[0]), Integer.parseInt(f[1])-1,    Integer.parseInt(f[2])-1900);  
}

public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException
{
    String path = "C:\\Users\\Alessandro\\Desktop\\eclipse\\Nuova Cartella (2)\\Biblio\\in1.txt";
    boolean esiste = true;
    File f1 = new File ("C:\\Users\\Alessandro\\Desktop\\eclipse\\Nuova     Cartella (2)\\Biblio\\src\\default.txt");
    f1.createNewFile();
    FileReader fr = new FileReader (f1);
    try
    {
        fr = new FileReader (path);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
(etc..)
```

now the other part of the program; before of this there is a switch and, prestiti is an ArrayList of the class Prestito.

```
case "D":
    Date data = parseDate (t[1]);
    //Arraylist per i libri in presto nella data fornita in input
    ArrayList <Libro> inPrestito = new ArrayList <Libro>();
    for (Prestito prestito: prestiti)
    {
        if(prestito.inPrestito(data))
        {
        inPrestito.add(prestito.getLibro());
        }
    }
    //ordinamo i libri in prestito
    Collections.sort(inPrestito);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("in data "+data+" i libri in prestito sono: ");
    for(int i=0; i<inPrestito.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(inPrestito.get(i));
    }
    break;
```

now the program take this problems out:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at prog1.parseDate(prog1.java:13)
at prog1.main(prog1.java:68)
```

how can i resolved it? i tried and tried to solve by my self, i've done a lot of research, but no results so far.

Comment: You should check what `s.split("/");` really returns. I expect  that `f` contains only one entry on index 0.

Comment: A lot of these types of bugs can be solved with the use of the debugger. If you are using Eclipse, start with [this link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html).